# Dependancy of files on archive in makefile

Tags: makefile

How to write a rule in a makefile which would extract an archive if it is newer than any of files extracted earlier?

Comment: It looks like I asked this question without imagine what I ask...

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment, even if this rule will be created it will "fire" almost everytime, because in most cases an archive is newer than any of files it contains.

I think an answer might be something like this:

```
timestamp: archive.tar.xz
    tar -xf archive.tar.xz
    touch timestamp
```